# Relay requests via setVariables

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

when a request is made via setVariables is there a way to take account of the local state in-between async requests i.e. to implement loading indicator ?

an illustration making requests to https://www.graphqlHub.com/graphql

```
  _onChange = (ev) => {
    this.setState({
      loading:true
    })
    let gifType = ev.target.value;
    this.props.relay.setVariables({
      gifType
    });
    this.setState({
      loading:false
    })
  }
```

this won't track the loading state and loading will pass on to false immediately while the async change to the view will have lag.

if we move loading into setVariables is there any way to track the response ? in the root container there is the ability to track response via

```
  renderLoading={function() {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }}
```

is there any similar method for `Relay.createContainer`

is it bad practice to use setVariables to navigate through data sets ?

full code

```
class GiphItems extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: false
    }
  }
  render() {
    const random = this.props.store.random
    return <div>
      <select onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} value={this.props.relay.variables.gifType}>
        <option value="sexy">Sexy</option>
        <option value="cats">Cats</option>
        <option value="goal">Goal</option>
        <option value="lol">LOL</option>
      </select>
      {this.state.loading ? 'LOADING' : <a href={random.url}><img src={random.images.original.url} className="img-responsive"/></a>}
    </div>;
  }

  _onChange = (ev) => {
    this.setState({
      loading:true
    })
    let gifType = ev.target.value;
    this.props.relay.setVariables({
      gifType
    });
    this.setState({
      loading:false
    })
  }
}
GiphItems = Relay.createContainer(GiphItems, {
  initialVariables: {
    gifType: "sexy"
  },
  fragments: {
    store: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on GiphyAPI {
        random(tag: $gifType ) {
            id
            url
            images {
              original {
                url
              }
            }
            }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setVariables](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#setvariables) method also accepts a callback as the 2nd argument which responds to the events involved with the data fulfillment and it receives a ['readyState'](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-ready-state.html) object that you can inspect:

```
this.props.relay.setVariables({
        gifType,
      }, (readyState)=> {
        if (!readyState.done) {
          this.setState({
            loading: true
          })
        } else if(readyState.done) {
          this.setState({
            loading: false
          })
        }
})
```

Comment: thanks, this is what i had in mind.   one thing to note tho i've noticed, this solves my problem for each new loading of data, but when a query is made to a previously state that has already been loaded the initial value in the request for readyState.done is true rather than false (i guess as it assumes it has already requested that data) this brings back the lag between transitions.

Comment: In the case of primed cache you can avoid the unnecessary `setState` call by slightly tweaking the condition from `readyState.done` to `readyState.done && this.state.loading`.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. What you have is a viable option in terms of dealing with loading screens for a particular component. But that can become a burden to implement for every loading scenario for each individual component.

Here's what you can do instead if to provide a more generic solution: You can set up a global event system in your React app that will broadcast a global state to each component based on whether or not a call is being made. And for each component that you need this for, you can subscribe to this global event from `componentDidMount()` and unsubscribe with `componentWillUnmount()`. As soon as your component sees a change in this global state, that component should call `setState()`, which will determine whether or not that component should display a loading scene or not.

This is a good resource to learn how to communicate between components to set up a global event system:
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

You can also use Facebook's Flux to implement this as well:
https://facebook.github.io/flux/

Hope this helps!